# Does "usage" files in Proguard shows all that were removed?

Tags: android, proguard

I am using Proguard in my app. When I go and check the "usage" file, it list down all the variables I have declared in my different classes. Does it mean that it has removed them or they are no more functioning well? Because when I verify the data at server end, it is coming properly but the "usage" file says that particular parameter was removed. What actually "removal" means?